# make a `git diff` with julia's LibGit2

Tags: git, julia, libgit2

I am trying to debug a problem for another person who has julia installed but not git. I would like to know which changes were done to a julia packages, so essentially the command `git diff`.

I am wondering if I can use LibGit2 for this? These commands get me petty close:

```
 repo = LibGit2.GitRepo(Pkg.dir("NCDatasets"))
 tree = LibGit2.GitTree(repo,"HEAD^{tree}"); 
 diff = LibGit2.diff_tree(repo,tree,"")
```

They return:

```
 GitDiff:
 Number of deltas: 1
 GitDiffStats:
 Files changed: 1
 Insertions: 1
 Deletions: 1
```

Assuming that I want to know the changes in the package NCDatasets.

So I know that one file was changed. How do I know, which one and how were this file changed?

Unfortunately, I do not get any further based on what I understood from here:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/stdlib/LibGit2/src/diff.jl

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/stdlib/LibGit2/test/libgit2.jl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
julia> for i in 1:count(diff)
           d = diff[i];print(d)
           println(unsafe_string(d.old_file.path), "\t",
                   unsafe_string(d.new_file.path),"\n---\n")
       end
```

This will print you each entry of `diff`. Unfortunately standard `print` for `DiffFile` does not print file name so I have added printing it below the standard print.

Notice, however, that this `diff` will not contain untracked files. The simplest way to catch them is to use `LibGit2.status` function and traverse all files in your repository using `walkdir`. This method also has its drawback as it will not detect deleted files which `diff` will contain. It should be possible to write a function that catches all cases by combining the both approaches.

Comment: This is really nice! Do you have maybe any ideas how to find out how the file was changed? (which were removed and which lines were added). It seems that the function git_diff_print is not wrapped in julia. So maybe this is not possible (besides wrapping the function myself...).

Comment: AFAIK you would have to wrap it yourself.